# Parsing SSH2 Results in PHP

Tags: php, phpseclib

I am running PHP vc9 NTS 5.3.28 on Windows Server 2003 Standard 32bit with phpseclib 0.3.6.  I am trying to creating a script that will connect to a Palo Alto Networks firewall and execute a command to hash a password.  I have the following code:

```
<?php
include 'Net/SSH2.php';

define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('hostname');
echo ">Logging in...\n";
if (!$ssh->login('user', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
echo ">Reading login results...\n";
/*echo $ssh->exec('request password-hash password test123');*/
$output = $ssh->read('user@PA-3020>');
echo $output . "\n";
echo ">Writing request...\n";
$ssh->write("request password-hash password test123\n");
$ssh->setTimeout(10);
echo ">Reading result...\n";
$output = $ssh->read('/^\$1\$.*$/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
echo $output . "\n";
echo ">Done.\n";
file_put_contents ('E:\PHP53\ssh2.log', $ssh->getLog());
?>
```

I have two problems with the above code:

1. If I leave out the setTimeout(10) then the code never exists the next $ssh->read.  If I have it in, then the code exists only after the timeout but does return results.
2. The results it returns are including a bunch of stuff that shouldn't be there:

   ?[Kuser@PA-3020> request password-hash password test123
   ?[?1h?=?[24;1H?[K
   $1$dgkhwrxe$kddYFmKCq9.zfiBKPAyN61

   ?[24;1H?[K?[?1l?>user@PA-3020>

I only want the line that starts with $1$ (line 3 above).  I figure it has something to do with the regex but I can't figure out what.

If I run the command interactively with PuTTY I get the following:

```
user@PA-3020> request password-hash password test123

$1$pxqhdlco$MRsVusWtItC3QiMm4W.xZ1

user@PA-3020>
```

UPDATE:

As per suggestions from neubert below, replacing the line with $output = $ssh->read... with the following code works:

```
$output = $ssh->read('/\$1\$.*/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
$output = preg_replace('/.*\$1\$/s','\$1\$', $output);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The results it returns are including a bunch of stuff that shouldn't
>   be there:
>
> ?[Kuser@PA-3020> request password-hash password test123
>   ?[?1h?=?[24;1H?[K $1$dgkhwrxe$kddYFmKCq9.zfiBKPAyN61
>
> ?[24;1H?[K?[?1l?>user@PA-3020>

Those are ANSI escape codes. You can use File_ANSI to remove them. More info:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#top

Anyway, my guess would be that you need to redo your regex. eg.

```
$output = $ssh->read('/^\$1\$.*$/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
```

Instead of doing that do this:

```
$output = $ssh->read('/\$1\$/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
```

The thing is...  ^ matches at the start of the line and $ matches at the end. Usually when you do $ssh->write(...) the command is echo'd back to you and then there's a new line and then you get your output back. So that'd prevent ^ from working. And as for the $ at the end.. well per your own example $1$ doesn't occur at the end of a line. So that's why your code isn't working.

Comment: I don't need to actually process the escape sequences so I didn't think I would need the File_ANSI module.  When I use the regex you supplied, I get the following: ←[Kchris@PA-3020> request password-hash password test123
←[?1h←=←[24;1H←[K
$1$

Comment: It looks like you're getting the $1$ that you were wanting. Or do you want the whole line that $1$ is on? If so then `\$1\$.*$` might work. Looking at your code again I guess you did have .* between the two $'s so I guess I misspoke when I said that the $ at the end of the line wouldn't work..

Comment: I need that whole line and nothing preceding the $1$.  I'm trying to get the "$1$dgkhwrxe$kddYFmKCq9.zfiBKPAyN61" string in the above example.

Comment: `$ssh->read()` is going to return everything preceding the regex. If you want to remove the characters before the `$1$` you'll need to do so outside of `read`. eg. `preg_replace('#.*\$1\$#','\$1\$', $ssh->read('#\$1\$.*$#'))`

Comment: Thanks!  Your code with the addition of the regex s (ie: '#.*\$1\$#s') option worked!  Not sure why the s option is needed though.